# Exception thrown when running Docker Compose in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, docker, selenium-webdriver, .net-core, docker-compose

My C# Selenium testing project runs in a Docker container. I can view the container in my localhost just fine, and the project builds successfully, but when I hit Docker Compose in Visual Studio, I'm hit with an error:

I am fairly new to both C# and Docker, and have tried researching the error and could not find anything actionable. I have reinstalled .NET in VS, I have removed and reinstalled all Docker containers and images, I've restarted Docker (and computer of course), and nothing has made a difference. I'm not getting any VS errors on my actual C# files, and don't know what to do at this point. Thank you in advanced for any direction or advice.

The code should open up Chrome in the container viewed through Localhost. The Linux container does show through Localhost successfully, but the following errors show instead:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Failure instantiating the fixture.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.Collections.Immutable.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
The program '[278] dotnet' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program 'dotnet' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: The description says some dll is missing. Probably you didn't copy all the required files into the docker

Comment: I reloaded our premade container. When this originally worked, I hadn't needed to manually load any files into the container, I just downloaded and added it from our server.